# Gawk one-liner byte interpreter that doesn't treat 1 and 01 as the same

Tags: awk

I have an input file in the form of a long sequence of bytes, with some notes in between. I provide an example at the bottom.

I've been looking for a simple one-liner in gawk to extract and print only some lines, which was trivial at first:

```
gawk '$4==01' input.txt
```

This fails when a comment line in the input file contains the number '1' (without prefix 0) and extract both lines.

**How can I improve the one-liner so that '01' is matching and '1' is not?**

Input example:

```
00000.000    00 3E 01 09 87
00000.000    57 3F 00 09 87
// Total Errors: 1
```

Desired output:

```
00000.000    00 3E 01 09 87
```

Actual output:

```
00000.000    00 3E 01 09 87
// Total Errors: 1
```

I've tried to force the comparison on strings (see this [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Strings-And-Numbers.html)), but without luck: `gawk '$4==01""'input.txt` and `gawk '$4""==01'input.txt` both output only `// Total Errors: 1`, same as `gawk '$4""==01""'input.txt`.

Comment: Use `gawk '$4=="01"'`, see https://ideone.com/3gGuhA

Comment: That was a permutation I didn't think of. Thanks, I'll gladly accept it as answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
gawk '$4=="01"' input.txt
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/3gGuhA)

In your code, `01` is evaluated as `1` and thus all lines where Field 4 can be evaluated to `1` are returned. Enclosing `01`  with double quotes enforces a strict string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is using regex, but I'd like to have a simpler alternative:

```
gawk '$4~/^01$/' input.txt
```